# Get values from twodimensional array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm passing an array with form params to process. It contains several rows with each multiple values. How can I retrieve the individual values?
This is the controller code:

```
params[:line].each do |line|
  ... 
end
```

Each "line" gives me these values and I want to retrieve each value, like "home_score_id":

```
["1", {":home_club_id"=>"11", ":home_score"=>"2", ":away_score"=>"4", ":away_club_id"=>"10"}]
```

**Update:**

This is the form, it has 12 lines where you enter match results:

```
= form_tag store_all_results_path, class: 'form-horizontal' do
  .control-group
    .controls
      = select_tag :gameround_id, options_for_select(@gamerounds.map{ |g| ["#{markup_gameround(g)}", g.id] })
  - 1.upto(12) do |counter|
    .control-group
      .controls
      = select_tag "line[#{counter}][:home_club_id]", options_for_select(@clubs.map{ |c| [c.club_name, c.id] }), include_blank: true
      = text_field_tag "line[#{counter}][:home_score]", nil, class: "small_text_field"
      = text_field_tag "line[#{counter}][:away_score]", nil, class: "small_text_field"
      = select_tag "line[#{counter}][:away_club_id]", options_for_select(@clubs.map{ |c| [c.club_name, c.id] }), include_blank: true
  .form-actions
    = submit_tag :submit, value: I18n.t('.general.save'), class: "btn"
    = link_to t('.cancel', default: t("helpers.links.cancel")), results_path, class: 'btn'
```

When submitted, it gives these POST parameters:

```
Started POST "/results/store_all" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-03 10:47:34 +0200
Processing by ResultsController#store_all as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "gameround_id"=>"3", "line"=>{"1"=>{":home_club_id"=>"8", ":home_score"=>"3", ":away_score"=>"2", ":away_club_id"=>"10"}, "2"=>{":home_club_id"=>"7", ":home_score"=>"4", ":away_score"=>"2", ":away_club_id"=>"12"}, "3"=>{":home_club_id"=>"", ":home_score"=>"", ":away_score"=>"", ":away_club_id"=>""}, "4"=>{":home_club_id"=>"", ":home_score"=>"", ":away_score"=>"", ":away_club_id"=>""}, "5"=>{":home_club_id"=>"", ":home_score"=>"", ":away_score"=>"", ":away_club_id"=>""}, "6"=>{":home_club_id"=>"", ":home_score"=>"", ":away_score"=>"", ":away_club_id"=>""}, "7"=>{":home_club_id"=>"", ":home_score"=>"", ":away_score"=>"", ":away_club_id"=>""}, "8"=>{":home_club_id"=>"", ":home_score"=>"", ":away_score"=>"", ":away_club_id"=>""}, "9"=>{":home_club_id"=>"", ":home_score"=>"", ":away_score"=>"", ":away_club_id"=>""}, "10"=>{":home_club_id"=>"", ":home_score"=>"", ":away_score"=>"", ":away_club_id"=>""}, "11"=>{":home_club_id"=>"", ":home_score"=>"", ":away_score"=>"", ":away_club_id"=>""}, "12"=>{":home_club_id"=>"", ":home_score"=>"", ":away_score"=>"", ":away_club_id"=>""}}, "commit"=>"Opslaan"}
```

In the controller, I want to go through each of the 12 lines and create a result record (when line is not empty):

```
 def store_all
    params[:line].each do |line|
      unless line[:home_club_id].blank?
        Result.create(home_club_id: line[:home_club_id], away_club_id: line[:away_club_id],  home_score: line[:home_score], away_score: line[:away_score], gameround_id: params[:gameround_id])
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your keys look like symbols (`:home_club_id`), they are in fact strings prefixed with a colon (`":home_club_id"`). Removing the colons from your view should fix the problem.

So instead of:

```
= text_field_tag "line[#{counter}][:away_score]"
```

Just write:

```
= text_field_tag "line[#{counter}][away_score]"
```

Since `params` is a [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) you can use either `line["away_score"]` or `line[:away_score]` in  your controller.

```
def store_all
  params[:line].each do |counter, line|
    unless line[:home_club_id].blank?
      Result.create(line.merge(gameround_id: params[:gameround_id])
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The second value in "line" is a `Hash`, thus access is possible with

```
line[1][:home_club_id]
```

Comment: It gives an empty result. This is the result from the POST request: "line"=>{"1"=>{":home_club_id"=>"7", ":home_score"=>"2", ":away_score"=>"1", ":away_club_id"=>"6"}

Comment: ok, thus you have a Hash in Hash, the key in the outer Hash seems to be an id field. You can easyliy access id and inner hash with params[:line].each_pair do {|id,line| line[:home_club_id] ...}.

Comment: Still gives an empty value, I have updated my question with more info.

Comment: When do you get an empty value, when you call params[:line]? By the way, when creating the Result is easier when using the existnig line-Hash merged with the missing gameround_id: Result.create(line.merge(gameround_id: params[:gameround_id])